# how to match one id with multiple comma separated ids

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table demo

```
ID        collectionID

1           1,3,4
2           3,5
3           30,35,2 
4           4,5
5           2,3,30
```

Now, I want to getting rows which collectionID=3 using MYSQL query.

desired output will be -

```
1           1,3,4
2           3,5
5           2,3,30
```

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: mysql `FIND_IN_SET() `

Answer (score 1):

Use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), like this:

```
SELECT *
FORM myTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', collectionID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select * from tbl_name where FIND_IN_SET("3",collectionID);
```